# Manage/Set Permissions in Active Directory via PHP LDAP

Tags: php, permissions, active-directory, ldap

Within my PHP LDAP code, I'm able to go in and create OU's (organizationalUnits), Groups, as well as Users within Active Directory. I can even go in and add Users to groups.

Now, I need to set security permissions for a specific OU that will allow other groups to have certain permissions such as: Read Members and Write Members. Within Active Directory this is done by right-clicking on the OU -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced and then adding a specific group with the permissions you want.

The purpose of this is to allow for Users associated with a particular Group to have permissions to add new Users within the OU, add Users to Groups, etc. Basically administer the OU on behalf of the domain/server Admin. In other words, when I login as a User that is a member of the group 'Admin', how can I allow that user to then add users to this OU without getting "insufficient access" errors?

My code that adds the OU is this:

```
$dn = "OU=Groups,OU=TEST1,OU=Clients,DC=EQC,DC=local";
$entry["objectclass"][0] = "top";
$entry["objectclass"][1] = "organizationalUnit";
$entry["OU"] = "Groups";

if( ldap_add($con,$dn, $entry) !== false) {
    echo 'Awesome Sauce! The OU was added.';
} else {
    echo ldap_error($con);
}
```

How do I manage/set permissions needed to allow the functionality above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible with PHP. However, we were able to create a shell script that runs and check Active Directory for new security groups and then updates the delegation rights.